# Very Specific Non-Duplicate VPN+Tor Question

Tags: vpn

I have been combing the forums for hours  to get a clear answer to a very specific question I have and I can’t find it.

If I am connected to an encrypted VPN like NordVPN and I use Tor Browser, can my VPN to see the traffic that I’m sending to Tor or is it a second encrypted Tunnel within that my VPN couldn’t break? Is the data being sent to the VPN completely vulnerable before it hits Tor or is there a protection level because of Tor that makes it inaccessible to my VPN.

Comment: Nobody, please show me where that has been answered. I went through at least 50 posts. All the discussions of VPN + Tor suggested that this could somehow reduce security. None specifically addressed if one connection could be nested in another. If its hidden in the same way it would be from an ISP than how could it be anything but better? I contacted my VPN’s technical support And they said that everything goes to their server first before Tor and if it was compromised it could be seen so they are mistaken then?

Answer (score 1):

Tor has its own encryption so your VPN provider can only know that you are using Tor.

And, literally, this question is still a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Your VPN will absolutely be able to see traffic to and from Tor since your entire connection wrapped in a VPN. They will hopefully not be able to decrypt it. To do that, they would also have to be sniffing exit nodes and running relays on Tor themselves.

Answer (score 0):

As per Google Translate from [Mike cruz](https://tor.stackexchange.com/users/22675/mike-cruz):

> My question is that in an Android mobile it gives me the option of vpn for the applications and in another also Android does not give me that option and if I activate the vpn the signal falls and I am left without imternet. I mention that the two phones are Samsung in which I have the problem is an A5 model while in which it works perfectly is a J1 hopefully someone can support me with some response greetings thanks

If you are on an android then you are using Orfox, which insists on connecting through Orbot VPN which makes use of the built-in VPN service.